# Appending to my csv using writerow in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a an excel sheet with one column, the header is Name and the row below it says Jerry. All i want to do is append to this using python with the header: Age then a row below that saying e.g. 14.

How do i do this?

```
with open('simpleexcel.csv', 'r') as f_input:  # Declared variable f_input to open and read the input file
    input_reader = csv.reader(f_input)  # this will iterate ober lines from input file

    with open('Outputfile.csv', "w", newline='') as f_output:  # opens a file for qwriting in this case outputfile
        line_writer = csv.writer(f_output) #If csvfile is a file object, it should be opened with newline=''
        for line in input_reader: #prints every row
            line_writer.writerow(line+['14'])
```

instead i get 14 and 14 i do not know how i get another header

What i have to start with is

```
Name 
Jerry
```

what i would like is:

```
Name   Age 
Jerry  14
```

Instead i get:

```
Name   14
Jerry  14
```

how can i ammend my above code?

Answer (score 1):

Use `next(input_reader)` to get the header and then append the new column name and write it back to csv.

**Ex:**

```
with open('simpleexcel.csv', 'r') as f_input:  # Declared variable f_input to open and read the input file
    input_reader = csv.reader(f_input)  # this will iterate ober lines from input file

    with open('Outputfile.csv', "w", newline='') as f_output:  # opens a file for qwriting in this case outputfile
        line_writer = csv.writer(f_output) #If csvfile is a file object, it should be opened with newline=''
        line_writer.writerow(next(input_reader) + ["Age"]))  #Write Header
        for line in input_reader: #prints every row
            line_writer.writerow(line+['14'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to accomplish here but for your sample case this can be used.

```
import csv

with open('simpleexcel.csv', 'r') as f_input:
    input_reader = list(csv.reader(f_input))

input_reader[0].append('Age')
for row in input_reader[1:]:
    row.append(14)


with open('Outputfile.csv', "w", newline='') as f_output:
    csv.writer(f_output).writerows(input_reader)
```

**Input:**

```
Name
Jerry
```

**Output:**

```
Name,Age
Jerry,14
```